# Spring jpa column defaultvalue

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to do the following

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="tier_id", columnDefinition = "INT default 1", nullable = false)
public Tier getTier() {
    return tier;
}
```

but while inserting the record I get
`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'tier_id' cannot be null`

I want default `tier_id` to be `1` if it's not set, but it's not working. How can I correctly set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default SQL value is only used if the column is not present at all in the insert statement.

But Hibernate doesn't omit columns in insert statements. If you create an entity instance with a null tier, and persist it, you're effectively saying Hibernate that you want to persist an entity with a null tier, and Hibernate explicitely sets the tier_id column to null, since that's what you told it to do.

So, if you want your entity's tier to be the tier with ID 1, then do it explicitely in your application code:

```
SomeEntity e = new SomeEntity();
e.setTier(em.getReference(Tier.class, 1));
em.persist(e);
```

Comment: So basically I have to fetch the tier I want from the database using TierDao for example, then set it to the entity, right? I was thinking there is a way to do it without querying for the tier, like all new records will begin with the tier that have the id 1. Maybe I'm thinking of it wrongly. Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: That's what em.getReference() does: it returns an uninitialized proxy, without querying the database.

Comment: Any idea how can I achieve the same using springs persistence context? I simply have daos as interfaces that implements CrudRepository. Should I get a reference to the EntityManager somehow? Any tip would be appreciated, thanks for the valuable info, still learning here :)

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-

Comment: I've enabled logging on mysql server and I tried both methods getOne() and findOne(), looks like they both query the database as they both showed up on the mysql log, having the exact same query, maybe the difference happens when the Entity references more entities (`Tier` only have primitive fields). Also when I try to save the Entity when using getOne() I get a crash, works just fine when I use findOne(). Crash log here: http://pastebin.com/3tLiVZaE Any information about this would be great, Thanks JB!